# How to debug a DLL in IDA Pro with 3 export functions

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ida

I have a 32bit DLL I am trying to debug.  I set up my process options to use:

- Application: "C:\Windows\SysWoW64\rundll32.exe"
- Input file:  the DLL I'm debugging
- Parameters:  "C:...\mydll.dll", #1 #2 #3.

I don't think these parameters are working correctly though.  The DLL is supposed to set up a socket for a network connection to beacon out to.  That code is in one of the exported functions.  But it doesn't seem like that code is being reached.

Tried a different number of parameters and parameter names, but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: From the help page for rundll32 - "Remarks
Rundll32 can only call functions from a DLL explicitly written to be called by Rundll32."

Try using the DLL in the normal way, then debug *that*.

What actually, are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's for a malware practice sample I'm working on to learn.  What I know is that this DLL will set up a network connection and beacon out to a domain.  I can see the API calls inside the ServiceMain function that is exported.  I just need to get this to run properly to set up that beacon so I can do some network analysis after that.